# Adding a datafile in an optional download group for ClickOnce

Tags: .net, clickonce

From the VS UI it seems I cannot assign datafiles to a download group.

If I change this to 'Include', the datafile gets installed to the app directory and not the data directory.

Is this possible at all, or am I chasing fairies?

**Update:**

The reason why I need this is due to our database being 20MB while the app is only around 5MB, and it is a pain for the users to update that all, even though there have been no database schema changes.

**Update 2:**

From MSDN it appears this an intentional limitation...

*This metadata is valid for all files where **IsDataFile** is **false** and all dependencies where **DependencyType** is **Install**.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you cannot.

I moved to a handrolled version of ClickOnce's functionality and used NSIS for the installer.